# Difference in filter syntax

Tags: python, django

In the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#s-lookups-that-span-relationships), there seems to be a difference between

```
Blog.objects.filter(
    entry__authors__isnull=False,
    entry__authors__name__isnull=True)
```

and:

```
Blog.objects\
    .filter(entry__authors__isnull=False)\
    .filter(entry__authors__name__isnull=True)
```

Is is the case?

Comment: What part of the documentation are you referring to? I'd imagine there isn't any difference in the resulting query from these as they are shown here

Comment: You imagine. But in the link I give in my question, just read a bit later on, there's a sample with 'Lennon' and I hope it helps understand why I post such a strange question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the documentation is trying to say is that if in your query's `authors` doesn't exist then django will return null at this point and then it would seem it would still continue to try to do `isnull` but comparing against the `authors` rather than the intended `name`, and thus showing potentially invalid results.

The suggestion they are showing in the documentation is to check that both the author isn't null and that the name is null.

So in answer to your exact question, the queries you've shown *should* produce the same results since they should get optimized to the same query.

If they weren't optimised then the would still produce the same results since you first filter out all those elements where the `author` isn't null

Example:

```
 query = Blog.objects.filter(entry__authors__name__isnull=True)
```

Case 1 - `entry__authors` is null

This would satisfy the condition since it would check against `entry__authors__isnull` therefore returning results with entries that don't have an author

Case 2 - `entry__authors` isn't null

Performs the check as written, looking for authors with a null name, returning results where entries do have an author, but those authors don't have a name.

Comment: Thank you very much, nice explanation.